# Memory leak issue with WPF TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I faced out a memory leak in the default Textbox of WPF.
I am not talking about the UndoRedo stack issue, where other posts exists.

The problem is reproducible with a simple Textbox within a Window. Just create the window, close it and call the GC like in the following Code.

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFMemoryLeak.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPFMemoryLeak"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBox UndoLimit="0"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
        {
            Window1 w = new Window1();
            w.Close();
            w = null;

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```

Now have a look in the Diagnostic Tools of Visual Studio. I took a Snapshot after each cycle of the loop. You can see a small increase of 24 bytes, which is caused by the TextBox. Some WeakReferences are not collected by the GC.

[image]

Can you tell me how you deal or fix this problem? Am I just wrong in my analysis or do you just ignore small leaks like this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you should ignore it as long as it isn't becoming a problem. In C# the garbage cleaner is usually best left alone.

Comment: That isn't enough memory to worry about. When you hit 2 gig - that's when you need to start thinking about whether all your users are 64bit or you need to optimise something. How many times do you envision a user opening and closing a window in a working day? 
If it's a lot then maybe you shoukd be making this a single window app. What weak references do you have there anyhow?